# Какую аннотацию поставить в функции интерфейса Dao для Rxjava

Tags: rxjava, insert, android-room

У меня есть две функции находящиеся в Dao для работы с Rxjava надо пометить аннотацией Single,Completable и т.д. ,но мне выдает ошибку

> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type public Flowable getEmployee(String name);

> error: Methods annotated with @Insert can return either void, long, Long, long[], Long[] or List.Completable insert(EmployeeAchievement employeeAchievement);

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM employeeAchievement WHERE achievementName = :name")
    public Flowable<EmployeeAchievement> getEmployee(String name);


    @Insert
    Completable insert(EmployeeAchievement employeeAchievement);
```

gradle:

```
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:2.4.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:2.4.1"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava3:2.4.1"

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

gradle должен быть таким

```
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.1"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.1"
    
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava3:2.4.1"
```